# How to sum complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis

$2.3e^{j14°}+1.8e^{-j60°}=3.29e^{-j17.7°}$

Can someone explain to me how they get $3.29e^{-j17.7^{\circ}}$?

I have tried converting to trigonometric but I don't get a good solution...(plus it's a little bit complicated).

Comment: Write down the formulas for conversion to and from the polar form.

Comment: If you are using a calculator, make sure it's set for *degrees*, not *radians*.  You can doublecheck the setting by asking for $\tan(45)$.  If your calculator is set for degrees, you should get $1$; if it's set for radians, you'll get $1.61977519$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\exp(jx)=\cos(x)+j\sin(x)$. Then simply add the real and imaginary part, then transform back to exponential form.

$$z=a+jb=2.3\cos(14°)+1.8\cos(60°)+j(2.3\sin 14° -1.8 \sin 60°)$$

Use your calculator to simplify the expressions to get $a=2.3\cos(14°)+1.8\cos(60°)\approx ...$ and $b=2.3\sin 14° -1.8 \sin 60° \approx ...$ or use the exact values.

Then

$$z = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\exp\left[j\arctan(b/a)\right]$$